# How to run a pyramid app in Google App engine

Tags: pyramid, gcloud

I have been trying to get pyramid to run in google app engine but is not working out.
I have tried to follow the instruction [here](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid-cookbook/en/latest/deployment/gae.html) but it seems obsolete because gae doesn't have appcfg.py anymore. I followed the flask app tutorial on app engine documentation combining it with the one above to get this:    app.yaml

```
runtime: python
env: flex

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3
threadsafe: false

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: contractors/static
- url: /.*
  script: auto
```

then main.py:

```
from pyramid.paster import get_app, setup_logging
ini_path = 'production.ini'
setup_logging(ini_path)
app = get_app(ini_path, 'main')
```

In appengine shell console, I cloned the project repo, installed everything in a virtualenv then tried to run `python main.py`
But it returns that the Distribution for my project was not found. I then used `easy_install paste` then the distribution error resolved but `python main.py` still couldn't run. Help!

Actually, this is frustrating. i keep wondering why aws,gcloud and azure clouds didn't include pyramid tutorial while flask and django are all there. The community doesn't also have working tutorial for these cloud services. Being a newbie, i'm thinking there's something wrong with pyramid.

Answer (score 5):

It seems like this Pyramid tutorial it's outdated. Also I think it is made to work with App Engine standard, as the 'dev_appserver.py' command does not work with the flexible environment (notice the env:flex tag in your app.yaml file).

Besides, I managed to get pyramid to work on App Engine Standard, similarly to a Flask application, by following this [Pyramid Documentation](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/introduction.html#build-single-file-applications):

Notice the line where you are configuring the server, if you use this direction and port(127.0.0.1:8080), you will be able to view the webpage from the [Cloud Shell preview](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/features#web_preview) 'locally'.

The **main.py** file:

```
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
from pyramid.config import Configurator
from pyramid.response import Response


def hello_world(request):
    return Response('Hello World!')

def bye_world(request):
    return Response('Bye!')

config = Configurator()

config.add_route('hello', '/')
config.add_view(hello_world, route_name='hello')

config.add_route('newHandler', '/bye')
config.add_view(bye_world, route_name='newHandler')

app = config.make_wsgi_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = make_server('127.0.0.1', 8080, app)
    server.serve_forever()
```

**app.yaml**:

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
service: default
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: main.app
```

As you are using third party libraries (pyramid) you [need to specify them](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/python-standard-env#setting_up_libraries_to_enable_development). First create the **requirements.txt** file and enter the following lines:

```
pyramid
repoze.lru
```

(repoze.lru library seems to be a pyramid requirement)

Create a directory via the CLI (named lib in this example), in the same path as the rest of the files, and install the libraries:

```
mkdir lib 
pip install -t lib -r requirements.txt
```

This command will install all the libraries listed in the 'requirements.txt' file and copy them to the 'lib' folder.

Now create a file called **appengine_config.py** that will direct the App Engine deployment to upload the libraries inside the 'lib' folder, and type in:

```
from google.appengine.ext import vendor

vendor.add('lib')
```

As a side note, you don't need to do this with Flask as it's a bundled library in App Engine, therefore you don't need to specifically upload the library.

Finally to test the application 'locally' in Cloud Shell, you can run in your CLI:

```
python main.py
```

And then use the [preview function](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/features#web_preview) in the Cloud Shell.

To deploy the application from your CLI:

```
gcloud app deploy
```

And see it in your browser by using the command:

```
gcloud app browse -s <service_name_defined_in_app.yaml>
```

In this example this command would be

```
gcloud app browse -s default
```

Comment: If you submit a PR to the [Pyramid Community Cookbook](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid_cookbook), I'd accept it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this worked for a single file app but i'm getting the error "pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'contractors' distribution was not found and is required by the application" on the cloud and i'm still unable to resolve the error .

Comment: @splbuddy Do you have the folder named 'contractors' in the same path as the app.yaml? 
The 'static_dir' element will search in the folder you specified (in your case 'contractors/static') and upload any files inside to your App Engine application.


When you do a request to '/static' in your application, i.e. '/static/<static_file>', this handler will serve the file stored in 'contractors/static/<static_file>'. See more about how this handler works [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#Python_app_yaml_Static_directory_handlers)

Comment: @Steve Piercy Sure I will take a look! Also if there is something unclear about the explaination let me know.

Comment: Yes @Joan Grau, I have the folder in the same path with app.yaml, my issues are DistributionNotFound error. And I guess it's because the cloud shell has python 3.5 while appengine is running python3.7, I'll try python2 and see what happens.  Thanks once more for the help.

Comment: I have given up, I did a basic pyramid project and deployed it but the distribution error is still showing. `pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'dos' distribution was not found and is required by the application`. I think the problem is that `pip install -t lib -r requirements.txt` is not copying the project distribution into `lib`. I don't know how to make it copy it.

Comment: @splbuddy Sorry I missuderstood your previous answer. I don't know exactly what the 'dos' distribution is, but if you want to install it via this command you need to add a line with its distribution name on the `requirements.txt` file. Otherwise you can install it with `pip install -t lib dos`. If they are libraries created by you, in the `appengine_config.py` you can add the path to the files you need to import, by adding `vendor.add('path_to_folder_containing_dos')`

Comment: @Joan Grau,  sorry for complicating things. The `dos`  is the project name. I created a project called `dos` that's just a pyramid example project (scafford). Tried uploading it, everything went fine but that `DistributionNotFound` error, stopped it from running. 
Thanks very much for all the helps

Comment: @splbuddy Seems like the issue is different then. You can post a new question with the details, so we can take a look at the issue and resolve it (hopefully!).